# React native forzar actualización en google play

Tags: react-native

Tengo una app para android creada con React Native. Cuando haya una nueva actualización en google play quisiera forzar al usuario a que tenga que actualizar la app para seguir usando. Como lo hacen ustedes. 
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El método que utilizamos nosotros consiste en un proceso que necesita una API y una base de datos.

Para obligar a actualizar, la APP debe consultar la versión registrada en la base de datos, por ejemplo la 2.3. Luego, obtienes la versión de la app con un método:

```
        PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        versionCode = String.valueOf(info.versionName);
```

Finalmente, comparas la versión. Si coincide no pasa nada, y en caso contrario, puedes abrir un diálogo que indica que es necesario actualizar, y si sales, te devuelve a la actividad de login (por ejemplo), de esa manera, no se podrá realizar nada. Recuerda que puedes también hacerlo mediante versionCode.